# Using user_id to echo user info on a view page in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to make a link to a viewpage with using the user_id to display the other user information like for example name and email. This is the link I'm trying to make:

```
<?php foreach($userdetail_list as $row) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="<?php echo base_url() . 'User/profiel_user/'.$row['user_id']?>">
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Now I'm trying to gather the user information that belongs to the user_id that I clicked on.
When I click on the link I do see that the link changes to the right user : User/profiel_user/6
But it says 404 Page not found

My User_model file:

```
<?php
class User_model extends CI_Model {
    public function getUserInfoByEmail($email) {
        $q = $this->db->get_where('users', array('email' => $email), 1);  
        if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
            $row = $q->row();
            return $row;
        }else{
            error_log('no user found getUserInfo('.$email.')');
            return false;
        }
    }
    public function getUserInfo($user_id) {
        $q = $this->db->get_where('users', array('user_id' => $user_id), 1);  
        if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
            $row = $q->row();
            return $row;
        }else{
            error_log('no user found getUserInfo('.$user_id.')');
            return false;
        }
    }
    public function getdata() {
        $this->db->where('user_id', $id);
        $this->db->from('users');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows()>0)
        {
           return $query->result_array();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

my full User.php controller file:

```
<?php
    class User extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('profile', $data);
    }
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        if ($_SESSION['user_logged'] == FALSE) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("error", "Please login first to view this page!! ");
            redirect("auth/login");
        }
    }
    public function userdetails($user_id) {
        //load the User_model
        $this->load->model('User_model');

        //call function getdata in de Product_model
        $data['userdata_list'] = $this->User_model->getdata();

        //get product details
        $data['user'] = $this->User_model->get_user_info($user_id);

        //laad view
        $data['main_content'] = 'profiel_user';
        $this->load->view('profiel_user', $data);
    }
    public function profile() {

        $this->load->model('User_model');
        if ($_SESSION['user_logged'] == FALSE) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("error", "Please login first to view this page!! ");
            redirect("auth/login");
        }

        $this->load->view('profile');
    }
}
?>
```

What I have on the view page (profiel_user.php) where the link is linking to:

```
<?php include_once ('templates/header.php'); ?>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 bg-warning" style="font-size:25px">
                <center>Gebruikersprofiel</center>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php foreach($userdata_list as $row) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
     </tr>
<?php } ?>
<?php include_once ('templates/header.php'); ?>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 bg-warning" style="font-size:25px">
            <center>Gebruikersprofiel</center>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope someone can figure out what I'm doing wrong and why I can not use the user_id to echo or display other user_information.

Database:
table name: users
And user_id is my primary key

Comment: I noticed you are using include_once to load your views on view page codeigniter has a better way http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#loading-multiple-views

Comment: thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method name is `userdetails` not `profiel_user` so change your href

```
<td><a href="<?php echo base_url() . 'User/profiel_user/'.$row['user_id']?>">
```

to

```
<td><a href="<?php echo base_url() . 'User/userdetails/'.$row['user_id']?>">
```